# How do I make an array have the size I input while running?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make my code work in a way that the size of an array is set to my input?

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
final int size = myScanner.nextInt();
int[size] numberHolder = {};
```

Comment: `int[] array = new int[size];`

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
final int size = myScanner.nextInt();
int[] numberHolder = new int[size];
```